# Internet Explorer 9 input padding issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

this is [my site](http://virtualmix.it/); as i can see there's an `input[type=password]` with `width: 100%;` and `padding: 0 5px;`. It works perfectly in all the major browsers, but if u try to open the site on Internet Explorer 9, the input padding act in a strange way...

Comment: What do you mean when you say the input padding acts in a strange way? I tested it in Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 and didn't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) css property

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a *Document Type Declaration(dtd)* statement at the top of the page. If excluded, IE will default to *quirks mode*.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just include `box-sizing: border-box;` in the style